# Time-series clustering with multiple seeds automated

Tags: r, time-series, cluster-analysis, tsclust

i am trying to use time-series clustering, following the excellent examples of https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dtwclust/vignettes/dtwclust.pdf . However, when I use partitional clustering, the seed is very crucial to the results. Is there an automated way, to run the clustering with multiple seed and show the one that yields the lowest total inter-cluster distance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a `control` parameter with `nrep > 1`, that will use multiple seeds, and you can choose which result to keep based on your criteria (a list of clustering results will be returned). You still need to pass one "starting" `seed` to `tsclust` though.

[Documentation here](https://rdrr.io/cran/dtwclust/man/tsclust-controls.html).

Comment: To clarify, you should still pass a starting seed in order to have reproducible results. If you don't pass a seed, it will still try different seeds, but the starting one will be random each time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing a `for` loop for this?

That is a great way to automate things!